# How to use ksoap2 on Android 3.0+ Honeycomb

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, android-3.0-honeycomb, ksoap2

So I created a simple hello world program that uses ksoap2 on Android 2.3 and it works perfectly fine. However, when I use the exact same code on Android 3.0 Honeycomb (actually I'm using Android 3.1), it does not work. The app doesn't crash or anything, but it seems as if the ksoap2 operations is not completed or doesn't respond. Even though I have added:

to my AndroidManifest.xml file, it seems like ksoap2 is not responding. I was wondering if I have to make any additional changes since I'm using the Android 3.0+ sdk? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are running the webservice request on the main UI thread, which is not allowed anymore in 3.0 upwards. Move it into an AsyncTask.

Comment: That was it...I put everything in a AsyncTask instead of the onCreate and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use another thread to call a webservice if the application which you are developing runs on the honeycomb (3.0) because UI thread does not support for this action otherwise it will be throwed out an exception called [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). for further information: [Designing For Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)

here is a tutorial about using soap on honeycomb without ksoap2
http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/3-party-kutuphane-kullanmadan-ksoap2.html